# Laravel api method with different response

Tags: laravel, rest, api

I am building Api server based on Laravel 6.
I have endpoint for unauthorized request. GET: `/user/dummyuser`
This method return JSON data for Dummyuser. Thats ok.

But, if I pass token as GET param in same endpoint, I need get additions data.
For example,
GET: `/user/dummyuser` response user information
GET: `/user/dummyuser?token=ABCD` response user information with additions

How can I manage it?

Comment: Hi, just use something like this: `if($request->has('token')) { return ...} ;`

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this function I wrote for my project :

```
public function __construct($includes = null)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->includes = $includes;
}


if (strstr($this->includes, 'order')) {
$products = $order->product()->get();
        if (count($products)) {
            return ((new ApiController())->respondWithTransform($products, (new ProductTransformer($this->includes))))->original['data'];
        }
    }
return null;
}
```

so if my route has includes='order' in it,then it will generate some extra data

here is a link for strstr:[strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your route is like this:

```
Route::get("/user/dummyuser/{token?}", "Controller@get_token");
```

Your method would be this, because any request with parameters or without, with Authentication or without, would work.

```
public function get_tag($token = "", Request $request)
{
    // alternative method
    if (($user = Auth::user()) !== null) {
        // Here you have your authenticated user model
        return response()->json($response);
    }

    // return general data
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

I hope I helped you.